# Is it possible to have an object method return a function object and if so how do you access it?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

For instance, if i have:

```
var model = {
    updateCat: function(cat){
         var foo1 = function(){
                 //do something
             };
         var foo2 = function(){
                 //do something else
             };
         return{foo1: foo1, foo2: foo2};
    }
};

model.updateCat.foo1(cat); //does not work
```

What is the best way to do what i am trying to do there? Would it be better just to create separate object methods?

Comment: Uhm, `model.updateCat().foo1()`

Comment: For this syntax `model.updateCat.foo1(cat)` you can create GETTER udateCat for model object

Comment: Just out of curiosity... what is `cat`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan -  it's a small, usually furry, domesticated, and carnivorous mammal.

Comment: @adeneo :D :D ghghhhhhh :) almost spit my coffee :) I know, silly question, but I was just interested to know if probably an XY-Q ahead...

Comment: haha `cat` is just an object with some properties that i wanted to update. so instead of having a different function for each property i could just use one update object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parentheses after `model.updateCat` such that it is `model.updateCat().foo1()`.  This is because `updateCat` itself is a function which needs to be called in order to return the foo1/foo2 object.

Also, it looks like the `updateCat` function takes parameter `cat`, not `foo1` so `.foo1(cat)` would be incorrect.

```
var model = {
    updateCat: function(cat){
         var foo1 = function(){
                 //do something
             };
         var foo2 = function(){
                 //do something else
             };
         return{foo1: foo1, foo2: foo2};
    }
};

model.updateCat(cat).foo1(); //does work
```

Alternatively, you can call the `updateCat` function inline to have `updateCat` be a reference to the result of that function.  Note that this only works if you're only using one `cat` since the result of calling `updateCat(cat)` is stored and the anonymous function is lost.

```
var model = {
    updateCat: (function(cat){
         var foo1 = function(){
                 //do something
             };
         var foo2 = function(){
                 //do something else
             };
         return{foo1: foo1, foo2: foo2};
    })(cat)
};

model.updateCat.foo1(); //does work
```

Answer (score 2):

Another interesting way that allows you to chain your methods:

```
var model = {
    updateCat : {
        foo1 : function( cat ) {
           // do tha thing
           return this;
        },
        foo2 : function( cat ) {
           // do things
           return this;
        }
    }
};

model.updateCat.foo1(cat);           //does work
model.updateCat.foo1(cat).foo2(cat); //does work
```

---

In your example, `updateCat` is a function that is not executed, so you don't execute it `()`, instead you try to use it like it's a object (`{}`) `updateCat.foo1` therefore you might get an error saying

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

for your `model.updateCat.anythingHereIsUnreachable( bla );`

Comment: Oh I like this. So instead of keeping the `updateCat` as a function just make it another object.

Comment: @RyanGittens Yes. You got it right. That's at least fun if you want to chain your methods similar like jQuery does, i.e: `.doThis().doThat().blabla();` it always points back to the fn / or / object (in your case) thanks to the `return this;`. If you're more a visual guy, think on that `return this` like it actually does this stuff:  `.updateCat.foo1(cat).foo2(cat)` > foo1 returns `this` which is actually your `updateCat` so now you have :`updateCat.foo2(cat)` etc etc if you chain more methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it into an object:

```
(function() {
  var foo1 = function() {}
  var foo2 = function() {}
  var model = {
     updateCat: {foo1: foo1, foo2: foo2}
  }
  window.model = model;
})();
```

Or if you want to use return keyword:

```
var model = (function() {
  var foo1 = function() {}
  var foo2 = function() {}
  var model = {
     updateCat: {foo1: foo1, foo2: foo2}
  }
  return model;
  // also return like this:
  // return { updateCat: {foo1: foo1, foo2: foo2};
})();
```

Now you can do:

```
model.updateCat.foo1(cat);
```